# Definite integral transform $\int_{x=a}^{x=b}f(x)dx=\int_{t=0}^{exp(-a)}f(-ln(t))\frac{dt}{t}$

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-transforms

I found that transform by `Chebyshev`: 
[image]

But it doesn't work with simple function in `Mathcad` test:[image]

What's wrong with this solution?

Comment: Your lower bound should be exp(-b), not 0.

Comment: It work, thanks! But in the original paper was this form(post was corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at the integral transformation

$$I=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\text{exp(-a)}f(-\ln t)\frac{dt}{t}$$

we let $x = -\ln t$ so that $dx=-\dfrac{dt}{t}$ and our integration limits become $$a=-\ln t \implies t=\text{exp(-a)}, \quad b=-\ln t \implies t=\text{exp(-b)}$$

therefore

$$I=\int_\text{exp(-a)}^\text{exp(-b)}f(-\ln t)\left(-\frac{dt}{t}\right)=\int_\text{exp(-b)}^\text{exp(-a)}f(-\ln t)\frac{dt}{t}$$

where the lower limit goes to zero as $b\to \infty$. In your test, $b$ is a small finite number. The original author must have deduced that $b\to\infty$ before writing equation $(30)$.

Comment: I studied that work more closely. Before the conversion `b` was only ∞. Now everything is clear. Thank you for the great answer!